How difficult would it be to replace this cabinetry in the kitchen myself?

I am trying to figure out how feasible it would be to replace this portion of cabinets in the kitchen while I save up enough money to be able to have a full kitchen remodel. I would find pre-made cabinets - I am not attempting carpentry!
Basically the wood has had lots of water damage over the years and I want to plug up some holes behind where we know mice are coming in, so removing and replacing seems the best option.
What would I need to do to be able to replace these with basic but similar looking cabinets? And what might the most difficult part be?
I just need tips and ideas from people who have experience in this sort of thing before I send myself head-first into something that might end up being too much.
I am about to start my YouTube research for DIY cabinet installing :-)
I would not attempt to do any of the plumbing.

The easiest route would be RTA (ready to assemble) cabinets.  They run the whole gamut on quality, but even very nice.  I replaced all of my kitchen cabinets a couple of years ago with this method, though I used clamps and glue to glue all the components together.  Many people do not and only rely on the fasteners.  Assemble, shim level, shim behind while you drive cabinet screws into the studs.  Pretty easy actually.

Thank you - I will look up RTA!

Your question is actually pretty broad and likely will be closed, but here are some tips:
Your best bet is to go to a cabinet store or the cabinet department of one of the big box stores, with your pic and ask the same questions. Have measurements with you.
They can tell you what is available to fit the space and your sink, ( assuming you want to use the same sink.) If you need to work within a budget,consider flat pack cabinets. Those are in a box and need to be assembled. Don't be afraid of them. They are easier to assemble than one may think and some are a very good quality all wood cabinet. (Avoid MDF or particle board cabinets.)
Hopefully you have the space to assemble the new cabinets before you remove the old ones.
With every home there are certain circumstances that are a bit unique to that home, but here is a basic idea of what to do to remove the old cabinets.
You need to remove the sink first. Turn off the water. Remove the supply lines. Remove the drain pipes.
Once the sink is out, remove the countertops. (They are likely screwed in from the underside.)
Remove any screws holding the cabinets to the wall.
Depending on how the plumbing is done, you may need to remove shutoff valves and ptraps to get the cabinets out.
Remove the cabinets.
Install the new cabinets in reverse order. Be sure to level the cabinets and screw each unit to the other.  (Again this is a simplified idea of what you need to do.)

Thank you, that's really helpful - the exact kind of advice I was hoping for!
